# Why does the Java compiler only report one kind of error at a time?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

I've a snippet

```
class T{
    int y;
    public static void main(String... s){
        int x;
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Here there are two error, but on compilation why only one error is shown?

The error shown is:

```
non-static variable y cannot be referenced from a static context
    System.out.println(y);
                       ^
```

But what about the error

```
variable x might not have been initialized
    System.out.println(x);
                       ^
```

Comment: Are you still compiling Java code by hand?  You may want to try developing within an IDE like Eclipse.  :)

Comment: @Eric, deciphering error messages from a compiler is going to be necessary for a long time to come -- regardless of how one executes the compiler. (Heck, nothing about this example says it _wasn't_ discovered in an IDE.)

Comment: @sarnold: I took the part where he quoted verbatim command line output from javac as evidence he was running javac by hand.  Perhaps I jumped to conclusions though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Java compiler compiles your code in several *passes*. In each pass, certain kinds of errors are detected. In your example, `javac` doesn't look to see whether `x` may be initialised or not, until the rest of the code actually passes the previous compiler pass.

Comment: But what about if we're working on a large program and having more than one error. Then it shows almost all errors?

Comment: @Mohammed Faisal - it is nothing to do with the number of errors.  It is all about the kind of errors that they are, and when the compiler would be able to detect them.  If you are finding this hard to understand, don't worry.  It is the kind of thing you learn in a "compiler writing" course.

Answer (score 5):

@Greg Hewgill has nailed it.

In particular, the checks for variables being initialized, exceptions being declared, unreachable code and a few other things occur in a later pass.  This pass doesn't run if there were errors in earlier passes.

And there's a good reason for that.  The earlier passes construct a decorated parse tree that represent the program as the compiler understands it.  If there were errors earlier on, that tree will not be an accurate representation of the program as the developer understands it.  (It can't be!).  If the compiler then were to go on to run the later pass to produce more error messages, the chances are that a lot of those error messages would be misleading artifacts of the incorrect parse tree.  This would only confuse the developer.

Anyway, that's the way that most compilers for most programming languages work.  Fixing some compilation errors can cause other (previously unreported) errors to surface.

Answer (score 2):

[The Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3a_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) ("Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools" by Aho, Sethi, and Ullman) describe several methods that compiler writers can employ to try to improve error detection and reports when given input files that don't conform to the language specification.

Some of the techniques they give:

- Panic mode recovery: skip all input tokens in the input stream until you have found a "synchronizing token" -- think of `;`, `}`, or `end` statement and block terminators or separators, or `do`, `while`, `for`, `function`, etc. keywords that can show intended starts of new code blocks, etc. Hopefully the input from that point forward will make enough sense to parse and return useful error messages.
- Phrase level recovery: guess at what a phrase *might* have meant: insert semicolons, change commas to semicolons, insert `=` assignment operators, etc., and hope the result makes enough sense to parse and return useful error messages.
- Error productions: in addition to the "legitimate" productions that recognize allowed grammar operators, include "error productions" that recognize mistakes in the language that *would* be against the grammar, but that the compiler authors recognize as very likely mistakes. The error messages for these can be very good, but can drastically grow the size of the parser to optimize for mistakes in input (which should be the exception, not the common case).
- Global correction: try to make minimal modifications to the input string to try to bring it back to a program that can be parsed. Since the corrections can be made in many different ways (inserting, changing, and deleting any number of characters), try to generate them all and discover the "least cost" change that makes the program parse well enough to continue parsing.

These options are presenting in the chapter on parsing grammars (page 161 in my edition) -- obviously, some errors are only discovered after the input file has been parsed, but is beginning to be converted into basic blocks for optimization and code generation. Any errors that occur in the earlier syntactic levels will prevent the typical compiler from starting the code optimization and generation phases, and any errors that might be detected in these phases must wait for fixed input before they can be run.

I strongly recommend finding a copy of The Dragon Book, it'll give you some sympathy and hopefully new-found respect for our friendly compiler authors.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of an error is that the compiler doesn't know how to interpret your code correctly. That's why you should always ignore errors after the first one, because the compiler's confusion may result in extra/missing errors.

Comment: What? You obviously didn't read the question both errors are completely valid it's just that the 2nd one doesn't show up until the first one is resolved

Comment: That's what I was trying to say: in this case, there are missing errors, rather than extra ones, because once the compiler encounters one error its later behavior can be unpredictable.

Comment: @Jesus - What? You obviously didn't read the answer, which said quite clearly that some errors might leave the compiler a bit confused such that not all errors get reported.

Comment: @nnnnnn Which is obviously not the case here.

Comment: It is only "obviously" not the case if you understand a lot about how the Java compiler is implemented ... or can infer it from its behavior.

Comment: @StephenC Parse tree's only produce odd errors on later lines when the parsed statement is incomplete not when the statement is syntactically correct but has another error the compiler can catch.

Comment: @JesusRamos - 1) not strictly true. You also get odd errors if a name binds to the wrong thing. (The errors are odd *from the user's perspective*; i.e. based on what he/she meant the program to mean.)  2) that wasn't my point. My point was that it is only OBVIOUS to someone who understands how compilers are implemented.